# Android ProgressDialog setButton text change after show()

Tags: android, onclick, progressdialog

Im am trying to change the ProgressDialog button text from its initial value upon certain events. This is the code I am executing to change the button (second setButton), but I recognize that it is actually the button creation method used initially...

```
ProgressDialog mRemoveProgress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
mRemoveProgress.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, getActivity().getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            updateRemoveNodeState(RemoveNodeAppEvent.USER_CANCEL);
                        }
                    });
    ...

mRemoveProgress.show();

    ...

mRemoveProgress.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, getActivity().getString(R.string.complete), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            updateRemoveNodeState(RemoveNodeAppEvent.USER_OK);
                        }
                    });
```

I cannot seem to find the right methods to access the ProgressDialog button in order to change its text and possibly behavior, i.e. setup a new onClick.

Any suggestions on how I could implement this instead of dismissing the current dialog and creating a new one with the required setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mRemoveProgress.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setText("");
```

From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getButton(int))